# Alert on an object based on date field

Tags: workflow

I have an object and their is a date filed called "Next Session Date" which is for the user to decide...
Now I have create and activated a work flow rule called "Next Session Alert" 
then tried the following

1. Criteria rule "Criteria Client Session Record: Next Review Date NOT EQUAL TO null"
2. formula evaluates to true "Next_Review_Date__c <> NULL" 
   which basically are the same! but I didn't not get any notification email

I also tried criteria rule "Next_Review_Date__c = TODAY()" worked only if i set the field to today's date but didn't work when i updated the field for example to tomorrows or different day other than today...

Any ideas what is wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
Next_Review_Date__c >= TODAY()
```

The criteria should be set to every time a record is created or edited if you want there to be an alert after every edit.

Also if your expecting a reminder a day before the actual date, you might want to use time based workflow to send a reminder alert n days before the Next_Review_Date__c

Comment: i tried this once before too "Next_Review_Date__c >= TODAY()"
but still it doesn't work when the date is not today's date and yes the evaluation is set to "created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria"...

Comment: Sorry My mistake ... I didn't pay attention to  "Immediate Workflow Actions" and "Time-Dependent Workflow Actions" that was my problem